# Re initializing Datatable in jquery using Partial view in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using DataTable JQuery library to do pagination and sorting. I am using Partial view which is being loaded through Ajax call. Below are the issues which i am facing -

There are Four tabs on the view each one using the same Model but with different record set. Let's name tabs as Allowed,Blocked,Time Limited.

1. Default Tab is Allowed. Applying DataTable on this works just fine. I mean, Sorting paging everything works just fine.
2. Clicking on other tabs say, Blocked or Time Limited disables the property of Sorting and pagination. I have tried to destroy the DataTable object but still no luck

Please see the code below

```
$table=$('#apptable').DataTable({
            //retrieve: reInti,
            "bDestroy": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc'], [2, 'asc']],
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                            null, // 1st column width 
                            null, // 2nd column width 
                            { "Width": "180px" },// 3rd column width
                            { "Width": "80px" }// 4th column width  
            ]
        });
```

I don't want to create different partial view for each tabs because each tab uses same Model, and views are similar.

Comment: Solved this by using class instead of using id

Comment: Using class it is not perfectly re-initialized properly!